# Problem in Greenstone Digital Library Software search output

Tags: configuration, software, library

I hope this is right community to post this question. 
 So In full text search the Greenstone Digital Library Software correctly retrieve the newspapers containing the searched term both in HTML and PDF format. The problems that I'm facing are:

1. In PDF format the searched term is not highlighted.
2. Also PDF and in HTML files, though it is highlighted, but the layout of the newspaper is broken

Is there any setting in the software that I need to configure?